# swig error: Extraneous #endif

Tags: swig

When I executed the swig command on my .i file, I am getting an error on an include file.

The error says:

```
../include/example.h: Error: Extraneous #endif.
```

The contents of the example.h file is as below:

```
#ifndef EXAMPLE_H
#define EXAMPLE_H

namespace my_example {

class BaseExample {
public:
    virtual ~BaseExample() {}
};

}

#endif /* EXAMPLE_H */
```

In the above code, the #endif correctly matches with #ifndef.
So, why is swig reporting "Extraneous #endif." ?

Comment: What else is in your .i file? Probably the problem is elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the problem and solved it.
I think, the file had BOM marks in the end of file.
So, I executed
:set nobomb

inside my vim editor, and the error went away.